# pygame window showing nothing on run

Tags: python, pygame, pygame-surface

I am trying to make a game with pygame, but whenever I run my game, nothing shows up until I close the window, then stuff appears for a second. I don't know what is going on but I think is has to do with my display.update. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
import colorama
import math
import random #All needed libraries
import time
import os

from colorama import init, Fore, Back, Style #All needed extras
from pygame.locals import (
  K_UP,
  K_DOWN,
  K_LEFT,
  K_RIGHT,
  K_ESCAPE,
  KEYDOWN,
  QUIT,
)

init()
pygame.init()

SCREEN_WIDTH = 400
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 400

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

running = True

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))

surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
rect = surf.get_rect()

screen.blit(surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))

rect.update()
pygame.display.update()
```

why isn't it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a matter of [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). The scene must be drawn in the application loop instead of after the application loop.
Furthermore [`pygame.Rect.update`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.update)  isn't doing what you'd expect. It is used to change the rectangle. You don't need it at all.

```py
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
        elif event.type == QUIT:
            running = False

# INDENTATION
#-->|

    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    surf = pygame.Surface((50, 50))

    surf.fill((0, 0, 0))
    rect = surf.get_rect()

    screen.blit(surf, (SCREEN_WIDTH/2, SCREEN_HEIGHT/2))

    #rect.update()                <--- DELETE
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me!

Comment: @kDev Thank you. You're welcome.